# Why use Material Design Lite (MDL) with Twitter Bootstrap in Angular2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, material-design-lite

Material Design Lite (MDL) and Twitter Bootstrap are both great cross device frameworks, MDL is popular for its cool material deign look and feel while Bootstrap is for its adoption rate, out of the box components and customisation options.

What are the benefits of using MDL with Bootstrap ? Is it even a good idea in the first place ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not use both at the same time. Not a good idea in the first place :)

MDL and Bootstrap are both front-end frameworks that mostly overlap. Having experience of both I don't see any good reasons to use both at the same time.

Comment: ...is that a quantifiable statement?

Comment: Well, it's an answer to a rather vague question. MDL and Bootstrap are both front-end frameworks that mostly overlap. Having experience of both I don't see any good reasons to use both at the same time.

Comment: Some questions are better left unanswered, especially if you can't answer with anything but your gut feeling... :o)

Comment: True, but it was not my gut feeling. It was based on my experience.

Comment: Then detailing that experience and your reasoning for your conclusion would make for a much more useful answer...